# How to fix Terminal being hung out on "Building initial module 4.15.0-23-generic"

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom, dkms

I have been trying to install my wifi driver and terminal gets hung up on

```
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...  
Building for 4.15.0-23-generic  
Building for architecture x86_64  
Building initial module for 4.15.0-23-generic
```

I have seen others say typing in your password and pressing enter (sometime multiple times) solves this but it still doesn't work for me.

When I this I begin typing and sometimes only a few characters are represented on the line, before the cursor is blinking again and nothing I type is put on the line.

I am on 18.04, and trying to install a broadcom wifi driver if that means anything. Any help would be appreciated, and if I need to give any other info let me know.

Additional information:

```
matt@vendr-soldier:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
[sudo] password for matt: 
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4) ...
Removing old bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  bcmwl
Version: 6.30.223.271+bdcom
Kernel:  4.15.0-23-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------
Status: This module version was INACTIVE for this kernel.
depmod...
DKMS: uninstall completed.
------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.30.223.271+bdcom
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Building for 4.15.0-23-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.15.0-23-generic
```

Comment: Please show us the exact/entire command string(s) that you used to install this dkms driver. Copy/paste them from the terminal into an update of your question. Report back to @heynnema.

Comment: **@heynnema** See edit.  **Matthew** Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1051642/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future... **;-)**

Comment: Thanks, yea I see them I'll try to do that in the future. @Fabby

Comment: At some point after this message, it will appear to have hung, but it is infact prompting you for your password. You have to enter it twice. Perhaps the response from Akshay gawade works if you don't have a password set or something? Solution to a similar / related issue found in this thread: https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu/issues/81

Comment: I have the same problem. Small progress: I straced the dpkg that caused this, and... it seems to write curses codes to stdout containing strings like "package configuration" and "Configuring secure boot".... but those do NOT end up on my screen. I am currently logged in remotely from an Xterm.

Comment: Update: The curses tool that is asking the questions (sometimes including a question for your password) is being called with stdout connected to /dev/null: l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Jul 10 16:04 /proc/17903/fd/1 -> /dev/null

Comment: Update2: Big progress: this is what's hanging whiptail --backtitle Package configuration --title Configuring Secure Boot --output-fd 12 --inputbox --   Enter a password for Secure Boot. It will be asked again after a reboot. 10 77

Comment: Hung at the exactly the same "Building initial module for 4.15.0-23-generic" but with "sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall". None of the password-enter-arrow keys combo worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

@Andrew McLeod is correct above. You have to enter your **root** password + press enter **twice**

Comment: I had the same problem while upgrading from 17.10 to 18.04 and this solved it

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered with same problem while upgrading 17.10 to 18.04.
pressing "enter" and "right" arrow simultaneously multiple times solved my problem..

Comment: I never tried pressing the right arrow key. But since i had very little installed on linux i just reinstalled 18.04 and everything worked fine. Didn't have to try entering passwords or anything.

Comment: I dont know why but the enter + right arrow key worked for me!

Comment: It’s not clear at what point to hit Enter Right Arrow! Whenever I try it, it gives only the character codes on the screen: ^[[C . In any event, after a while, the screen turns black except for terminal; a while longer the cursor no longer moves and after another while terminal closes and it goes back to the desktop. All along there is hard drive activity.

Answer (score -1):

This is so frustrating. I have been searching blogs and forums for 2 days and no one has a solution that works. I tried to install Virtualbox when this same thing happened to me. Virtualbox is now installed but I still can't get the terminal to go past "Building initial module for 4.15.0-23-generic" when trying to install the Virtualbox Extension Pack or an updated version of Virtualbox. Entering my password or right arrow+enter doesn't do anything.

Comment: This is a question, not an answer.